# MongoDb $set value of field after identifying the object within the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

in Mongo `$set` operations, How can I identify a particular object within an `array` by matching the field `'idGen'` to a variable called `'id'`. So, by matching the `'idGen'` to the variable `'id'` within this object, how can I set the `value` variable to the field called `fieldStr` within this object?

On the server, I find the the collection by matching the userId like this.

```
var id
var fieldStr
var userId = this.userId
```

I tried:

```
Collection.update(
{'createdBy': userId, 'array.$.idGen': id},
{$set: 
      {'array.$.fieldStr': value}
})
```

So as you can see, the `'idGen'` field is the unique field of every object within the array.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out.  I dont know if I should delete my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection.update({'createdBy': userId, 'array': {$elemMatch: {idGen': id}}}, {$set: {'array.$.fieldStr': value}})
```

The elemMatch matches the object within the array with the 'id' variable idGen matching to the 'id' variable. The `$` is my placeholder in order to target the 'fieldStr' field which I can then set the value to.